# Dataset standarization in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to do data standardization that is to convert my dataset into columns of mean 0 and standard deviation 1 . My data resides in the hive . Is there any function exists in hive that can do the same for me like scale(dataset) in R.

Answer (score 1):

As fat as I know, there is not a Hive equivalent for such an operation. You may check this list of [Hive operators and User-Defined Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF). If not existing, you may create your own UDF regarding the required operation; it is described at the end of the link.